# Dunning email sending queue gives the error - DUNNING_STATEMENT_PRINT_ERROR when trying to send the letter

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, email-templates, suitescript1.0

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

We created a custom statement form (Made form is preferred) and attached a custom print template (Advanced PDF Template) instead of the Standard Multi-currency Statement Template . For some customers we are getting the error - DUNNING_STATEMENT_PRINT_ERROR while for some we are not and letters are being sent correctly .

Comment: Have you tried manually printing the statement for those customers who you are getting errors for?  The error could be coming from the template and if so you may be able to replicate it outside the dunning module and thereby make troubleshooting easier.